# Removing one of the symmetric items in PySpark RDD

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I have a list which contains only 4 numbers. I want to do cartesian multiplication, but in my case because there is no difference between `(x,y)`  and `(y,x)`, I want to delete one of them to avoid redundant calculations later. I removed the diagonal items using the filter operations, but I couldn't remove one of the symmetric items.

```
data = [1,2,3,4]

from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

dataRDD = sc.parallelize(data)
newRDD = dataRDD.cartesian(dataRDD)
newRDD = newRDD.filter(lambda x : x[0]!=x[1]) # removing diagonal items
newRDD.collect()

#expected output:
[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)]
```

I had the idea that maybe converting the items to a `set` in python and doing distinct operation would solve the problem. And I got error because sets are unhashable ...
so I came with this idea that maybe I can convert them to `set` and then I can convert it to `str`
which is okay with `distinct` operation in `pyspark`, but I didn't get the correct results :/

In the above example maybe the idea I mentioned would work, but in my own data it works sometimes and sometimes doesn't.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would changing the filter to `x[0]<x[1]` help?